# How to send Message to particular Receiver using JMS Queue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, hornetq

Is it possible to send message to particular receiver using JMS Queue(HornetQ)?

Among so many receivers, I want certain message to be received by receiver which
are running on Linux OS.

Every suggestion is appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set a message property using [Message.setObjectProperty(String, Object)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setObjectProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) and then have your consumers select the messages they are interested in using [Session.createConsumer(Destination, String)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createConsumer%28javax.jms.Destination,%20java.lang.String%29)

Sender example:

```
Message message = session.createMessage();
message.setObjectProperty("OS", "LINUX");
producer.send(message);
```

Receiver example:

```
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination, "OS = 'LINUX'");
//Use consumer to receive messages.
```

The receiver in the example will ignore (they will go to some other receiver) all messages that do not match the selector. In this case all message where the 'OS' property is not 'LINUX' will be ignored by this consumer.

Comment: How the above solves the problem? I am facing the issue after changing the above?

Comment: Even though this doesn't actually solve the problem it is a very good insight into the creation of JMS consumers. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

You can set properties of JMS message: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/TextMessage.html and filter messages at client side.
For example, 
message.setStringProperty("TARGET_OS", "LINUX") - at sender
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-detect-os-in-java-systemgetpropertyosname/ - detect OS at receivers and filter messages with correct TARGET_OS property

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Can you please elaborate on this?, Now I am able to send message with properly but How do I receive it? Or where I need to set property for Receiver side?

Comment: You can check property at receiver side and ignore messages if receiver is not interested. Or you can use JMS selector: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JMS4.html if your JMS implementation supports it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMS selectors on the consumer side to look for messages that fit specific criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am missing something, you could keep things simple by having multiple queues - specific to each platform, then the linux based consumers can listen to the linux specific queue alone. Now your challenge probably will be to route the messages to the appropriate queue from the producer side, that should be fairly easy if the routing is based on some attribute of the message?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but actually I am not supposed to create new queue for this as per requirement.